# Bootstrap Mobile Dropdown menu works on simulated viewport but not actually on mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

See the following herokuapp.

https://islandrelief.herokuapp.com/

On desktop, when the browser size is small the dropdown menu is clickable. However on mobile, it doesn't want to be clicked at all! At least from my iPhone 5. Here is the navbar code:

```
 <!-- navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header" style="height: 130px">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZrE6KrY.png" style="width: 150px"></a>
          <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav">
            <li class="login-mobile"><br>
              <div style="float: left; width: 50%; text-align: right;">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>&nbsp;
              </div>
              <div style="float: right; text-align: left; width: 50%;">
                &nbsp;<button class="btn btn-success" >Login</button>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navbar-link-custom" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px;" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navbar-link-custom" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px;"href="#">ATTRACTIONS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navbar-link-custom" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px;"href="#">EVENTS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navbar-link-custom" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px;"href="#">LATEST</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navbar-link-custom" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px;"id="rightMostLink" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navbar-link-custom socialIcon" >|</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navbar-link-custom sm socialIcon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navbar-link-custom sm socialIcon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navbar-link-custom sm socialIcon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navbar-link-custom sm socialIcon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-snapchat"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<a class="navbar-toggle">` needs an `href` attached to make it clickable in mobile safari.  Updating it to:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

fixed the issue for me.

Comment: god bless you sir